# How to move div inside another in on responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to move my p element inside in `.a` to `.b` div on responsive for example on 768px how can I do that ?

```css
div{margin:10px;
padding:10px;}
.a{
background:#f0f0f0;
border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.b{
background:#999;
border:1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
<p>lorem ipsum dolor site amet...</p>
</div>

<div class="b">

</div>
```

Comment: You can't change html structure by css. Only using js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution by using some jquery code (more specific, the [.resize() function](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)) and by adding an id to the < p> element you want to move (#moveElement):

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('#moveElement').appendTo('.b');
  } else {
    $('#moveElement').appendTo('.a');
}});
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ypx5vr5/1/) to see a working example.

Comment: thanks a lot..so can we make this for mobile ? not only resize both resize and mobile without resizing

Comment: That's a case of defining proper css rules according to the size of your screen(-width). A simple search for 'using css media queries' should give you enough sources that van help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the `window` width and then use `appendTo()` method to move the element from `.a` to `.b`, like this:

```js
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
  $('.a p').appendTo('.b');
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.a {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.b {
  background: #999;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <p>lorem ipsum dolor site amet...</p>
</div>

<div class="b">

</div>
```

If you want to see it on resize of the browser you can use `$(window).resize(function(){ //your code here... })` alongside with the code above. Something like this:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('.a p').appendTo('.b');
  }
}).resize();
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.a {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.b {
  background: #999;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <p>lorem ipsum dolor site amet...</p>
</div>

<div class="b">

</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much it works and I've question too.when I resize window it works very well but when I entered from my mobile device than it's working why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, right. You can't change your HTML structure by using Css. It can be done with some lines of code.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var a = document.querySelector('.a');
    var b = document.querySelector('.b');
    var c = document.querySelector('p');

    window.addEventListener('resize', function (event) {
        if (768 >= window.innerWidth && 'a' === c.dataset.location) {
            b.appendChild(c);
            c.dataset.location = 'b';
        } else if (768 < window.innerWidth && 'b' === c.dataset.location) {
            a.appendChild(c);
            c.dataset.location = 'a';
        }
    });
}, {once: true});
```

```css
div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.a {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.b {
    background: #999;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <p data-location="a">lorem ipsum dolor site amet...</p>
</div>

<div class="b">

</div>
```